# Encode a string using windows 1252 in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, windows-1252

I want to encode a string in Node.js using windows-1252 encoding scheme. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem when retrieving data from old websites with ANSI (windows-1252) encoding. Some characters come out messed up. like: ���

Here is how I solved. Based on the [API doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

```
var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
```

Just change `res.setEncoding('utf8');` into `res.setEncoding('binary');`. It seems to accept both `utf8` and `ansi` encoding without messing the accents.

```
res.setEncoding('binary');
```

Comment: Wow I would have never found this myself. This fixed a problem while importing CSV files created in Windows. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use any of these packages. Just go through the guide. First one is exactly meant for what you need. The other one takes care of many more 
legacy encoding.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1252

https://www.npmjs.com/package/legacy-encoding